# TypeScript and Redux: Why do I need to add ` | undefined` to my Reducer state type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

Why can I not just type my reducer simply like this, without adding " | undefined" to my redux state type?

```
const reducer: Reducer<ReduxState> = function(state: ReduxState, action: any) ...
```

Extra context::::

This works OK:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<ReduxState | undefined> = function (
    state: ReduxState | undefined, 
    action: any
) {
    return state
}
export default reducer
```

However, it doesnt when taking away state parameter "undefined" from fxn:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<ReduxState | undefined> = function (
    state: ReduxState, 
    action: any
) {
    return state
}
export default reducer
```

Which gives an error of:

```
Type '(state: ReduxState, action: any) => ReduxState' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<ReduxState | undefined, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReduxState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReduxState'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReduxState'.ts(2322)
```

Or this:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<ReduxState> = function (
    state: ReduxState | undefined, 
    action: any
) {
    return state
}
export default reducer
```

which gives an error msg of:

```
Type '(state: ReduxState | undefined, action: any) => ReduxState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<ReduxState, AnyAction>'.
  Type 'ReduxState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReduxState'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReduxState'.ts(2322)
```

And lastly, this doesn't work either:

```
import {ReduxState, ReduxAction, ReduxActionType} from './types'
import {Reducer} from 'redux'

export const reducer: Reducer<ReduxState> = function (
    state: ReduxState, 
    action: any
) {
    return state
}
export default reducer
```

With an error msg of :

`Type '(state: ReduxState, action: any) => ReduxState' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<ReduxState, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReduxState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReduxState'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReduxState'.ts(2322)`

TL; DR:  Typescript isn't happy with my Reducer unless I specifically allow "ReduxState | undefined" type in both the `Reducer<ReduxState|undefined>` and `function(state: ReduxState | undefined)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for the initial state, the previous state is undefined. Therefore your function has to be able to deal with `state` being `undefined`, thats what the first error tells you.

The second version doesn't work, because you `return state`, and that can be undefined (as you don't check if it is not defined), and therefore the return type of that function (which is the generic argument to `Reducer`) also have to be possible undefined. You could guard against that:

```
  if(state === undefined)
     return { /*...*/ };
  else return state;
```

then `Reducer<ReduxState>` would describe the type correctly.

Comment: I don't get it, now I have to have it in all my actions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should give your state a default value, like

```
import {ReduxState, ReduxAction, ReduxActionType} from './types'
import {Reducer} from 'redux'

const defaultState = {
    // your default state
}

export const reducer: Reducer<ReduxState> = function (
    state = defaultState, 
    action: any
) {
    return state
}
export default reducer
```