# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined' error on React/Redux initialState

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

I'm receiving a lint error ***Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'*** on my initialState when creating the store and I'm struggling hard with it.

Here is a simplified representation of the relevant parts:

```
export interface IGeneric {
  aString: string;
  aNumber: number;
}

interface IAppState {
  currentSection: string;
  experiences: IGeneric[] | [];
  finishedScenario: boolean;
  formation: IGeneric[] | [];
  language: LanguageCode;
  languages: IGeneric[] | [];
  projects: IGeneric[] | [];
  skills: IGeneric[] | [];
  texts: IGeneric | Record<string, never>;
  textsDatabase: IGeneric | Record<string, never>;
}

const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
  currentSection: 'main',
  experiences: [],
  finishedScenario: false,
  formation: [],
  language: 'en',
  languages: [],
  projects: [],
  skills: [],
  texts: {},
  textsDatabase: {}
};


let store: Store;

export const getStore = (): Store<IAppState> => {
  if (!store) {
    store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      INITIAL_STATE, // error here
      compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, updateTexts), devToolsEnhancer())
    );
  }
  return store;
};
```

[image: initial state error image]

Any ideas on how can I solve it?
Thanks!

**UPDATED:**

It seems like in my combineReducers, all my states values are initialized *undefined* by default, as according to Redux definitions, [all reducers are passed undefined on initialization](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)
So, ok. I get that part... but the question remains... how to counter it and make my createStore accept both undefined and the real interface for its initial state??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after struggling really hard and reading thounsands of docs I was able to find a solution. I post it here in the case it may of any help to others in the future.

What really opened my mind was [this Github issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2578) and [this discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798148/typescript-and-redux-why-do-i-need-to-add-undefined-to-my-reducer-state-ty).
What I was missing was:

"*[With combineReducers, each slice reducer is expected to "own" its slice of state. That means providing an initial value in case the current slice is undefined, and combineReducers will point out if you're not doing that.](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2578#issuecomment-331964833)*"

and

"*[Your reducers currently do nothing except return whatever's passed in. That means that if state is undefined, they will return undefined. So, combineReducers() is telling you you're breaking the result that it expects.](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2578#issuecomment-434894103)*"

Thus, it became clear that my issue was happening on my conbineReducers and I rewrote its type definition to allow for undefined values.

Here is its final implementation (to simplify, real interfaces were changed for *IGeneric*):

```
type IActionReducer<T> = (state: T, action: IAction<T>) => T;

interface RootReducer {
  currentSection: IActionReducer<IGeneric| undefined>;
  experiences: IActionReducer<IGeneric[] | [] | undefined>;
  finishedScenario: IActionReducer<boolean | undefined>;
  formation: IActionReducer<IGeneric[] | [] | undefined>;
  language: IActionReducer<IGeneric| undefined>;
  languages: IActionReducer<IGeneric[] | [] | undefined>;
  projects: IActionReducer<IGeneric[] | [] | undefined>;
  skills: IActionReducer<IGeneric[] | [] | undefined>;
  texts: IActionReducer<IGeneric| Record<string, never> | undefined>;
  textsDatabase: IActionReducer<IGeneric| Record<string, never> | undefined>;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  currentSection,
  experiences,
  finishedScenario,
  formation,
  language,
  languages,
  projects,
  skills,
  texts,
  textsDatabase
} as RootReducer);

export default rootReducer;
```

I really hope this helps someone with similar issues. :)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't put the closing quote of the first prop in the initial State. Your initial State should:

```
const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
  currentSection: 'main',
  ....
};
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. But this was a mistake when "simplifying" the component to display it here. The real currentSection points to a string constant defined on another file. Anyway, it is now corrected. Thanks.

Comment: This type of post should be a comment, not an answer.